# perl sybase : capture stored procedure print and select statement

Tags: perl, printing, sybase, procedure

i have a stored procedure which has a lots of print statement and it results both print statement and a resultset

how do i capture print statement and select statement seperately using perl and (DBI/DBD or CTLib or DBLib)

Comment: [Capture::SystemIO](http://p3rl.org/Capture::SystemIO) [Capture::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Capture::Tiny) [IO::Capture](http://perl.org/IO::Capture) [IO::Capture::Extended](http://perl.org/IO::Capture::Extended) [IO::CaptureOutput](http://perl.org/IO::CaptureOutput) [IPC::Capture](http://perl.org/IPC::Capture) and that's just those which have "capture" in their name. This question has great potential to show off "more than one way to do it".

Answer (score 1):

[http://search.cpan.org/~mewp/DBD-Sybase-1.12/Sybase.pm#syb_err_handler_(subroutine_ref)](http://search.cpan.org/~mewp/DBD-Sybase-1.12/Sybase.pm#syb_err_handler%5F%28subroutine_ref%29) says:

> **syb_err_handler (subroutine ref)**
> This attribute is used to set an ad-hoc error handler callback (ie a perl subroutine) that gets called before the normal error handler does it's job. If this subroutine returns 0 then the error is ignored. **This is useful for handling PRINT statements in Transact-SQL**, for handling messages from the Backup Server, showplan output, dbcc output, etc. [emphasis mine]

And shows the following way to handle this:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Sybase:server=troll', 'sa', '', 
                { syb_err_handler => \&err_handler });
```

The other thing that I used to do, knowing that my procs would mainly be called from perl was "select" all printed output with the first column being "Message: " and the second column as the message I wanted to print. I even created a sort of printf-from-the-database function around this.